# Потоки Java и их закрытие

Tags: java, многопоточность

Зачем нужно закрывать потоки? Читал статью о том как читать/записывать в файл и из него и увидел метод `close()`, который применялся к читающему, если так можно сказать, потоку.

Comment: Чтобы освободить ресурсы. В операционной системе может быть одновременно открыто ограниченное количество файлов.

Comment: Потоки надо закрывать чтобы не тратились лишние ресурсы как и сказал @Sergey Gornostaev. Вообще потоки очень щепетильная тема. Особенно их закрытие. Вот хорошая статья на тему закрытия потоков. Простая и емкая
[https://habrahabr.ru/post/133413/](https://habrahabr.ru/post/133413/)